# iOS how do I reset button images?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a few buttons that when pressed they change from a plain button to a button with a picture of a tick. The problem I have is that I can't then get a ticked button back to an untucked button when a separate button is pressed. Is this possible at all?

Here are my buttons:

```
    - (IBAction)pickCat:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self deselectAllButtons];

    ((UIButton *)sender).selected = true;

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white - on.png"];
    [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];



    self.catLabel.text = @"WHITE (Hi-Po)";

}
- (IBAction)pickCatb:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self deselectAllButtons];

    ((UIButton *)sender).selected = true;

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red - on.png"];
    [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    self.catLabel.text = @"RED (Significant)";

}
- (IBAction)pickCatc:(id)sender {

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow - on.png"];
    [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.catLabel.text = @"YELLOW (Serious)";

}
- (IBAction)pickCatd:(id)sender {

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green - on.png"];
    [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.catLabel.text = @"GREEN (Important)";

}
- (void)deselectAllButtons
{
    // assuming you have a reference to all your buttons
    self->Btn1.selected = false;
    self->Btn2.selected = false;

}
```

Comment: so basically treat them as radio buttons? click on in a group and the rest in the group go unchecked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to set a different image for each state: normal and selected. It looks like you're using Interface Builder, and it's really easy to set up your buttons with different images for a normal and a selected state.

[image]

Then in your code you can do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)pickImage:(id)sender {

    [self deselectAllButtons];

    sender.selected = true;

    self.locLabel.text = @"Red";

}
- (IBAction)pickImageb:(id)sender {

    [self deselectAllButtons];

    sender.selected = true;

    self.locLabel.text = @"Red";

}

- (void)deselectAllButtons
{
    // assuming you have a reference to all your buttons
    self.btn1.selected = false;
    self.btn2.selected = false;
    ...
}
```

If you want to be able to reset all buttons before changing one to a checked image, you have to have a reference to everything else you want to affect. If you want to get fancy, look into [Outlet Collections](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/28/interface-builder-outlet-collections.html) so you can easily loop through an array of buttons from your IB file and set their selected state to false.

UPDATE:

Here's how your code should probably look:

```
- (IBAction)pickCat:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self deselectAllButtons];

    // no need to cast since you changed your method signature.
    // the system now expects sender to be a button
    // ((UIButton *)sender).selected = true;
    sender.selected = true;

    // no need to set the image explicitly. if you did things correctly
    // in IB, you've already told the button which image to use when
    // selected, and which image to use when not (default). when you set
    // the line above (sender.selected = true), that will tell the button
    // to go use the image that you added to the button's selected state in IB
    // UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white - on.png"];
    // [sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.catLabel.text = @"WHITE (Hi-Po)";
}

- (IBAction)pickCatb:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self deselectAllButtons];

    sender.selected = true;

    self.catLabel.text = @"RED (Significant)";
}

- (IBAction)pickCatc:(id)sender {
    [self deselectAllButtons];

    sender.selected = true;

    self.catLabel.text = @"YELLOW (Serious)";
}

- (IBAction)pickCatd:(id)sender {
    [self deselectAllButtons];

    sender.selected = true;

    self.catLabel.text = @"GREEN (Important)";

}
- (void)deselectAllButtons

{
    // 2 things:
    // 1) I'm not sure about self->Btn1. why not self.Btn1? 
    // 2) it looks like you have 4 buttons (catA, catB, catC, catD). if so, you need to set the selected state for all of them to false
    self->Btn1.selected = false;
    self->Btn2.selected = false;

    self->Btn3.selected = false;
    self->Btn4.selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi @djibouti33 I have tried adding this to my code but it still seems to leave the ticks showing in all the boxes. I will update with how my code looks now.

Comment: are you using IB as I suggested above, to dictate the selected and non-selected image for each button? also, you're setting `selected=false` in `deselectAllButton`, but you're not setting it to true when the user taps on a particular button.

Comment: I've selected the different images for the different states in the IB. When I add sender.selected = true; it comes back with the error Property 'selected' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: ahh...look at your method declarations. `- (IBAction)pickImage:(id)sender` - that method expects `sender` to be of type `id`. You can either change it to `- (IBAction)pickImage:(UIButton *)sender` (which will also require that you rewire that method to the button in IB since technically it's now a new method, or inside the method you can cast sender to a UIButton - `((UIButton *)sender).selected`

Comment: I've updated my code. Is this how it should be looking, as the images are still not going back to its original default image?

Comment: i updated my answer with a code sample. check that out.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! Still not sure why it won't work with self.Btn1 though.